# How to call function after fetch() has finished

Tags: javascript, react-native, response, fetch-api

I am using react-native and I have fetch GET request which takes an array. Now I need this fetch() to finish getting that array so I can call a function which will handle this array and do something with it. How do I wait for it to finish?

This is my request:

```js
componentWillMount() {
  console.log("will mount");
  fetch('SOME_API', {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: 'text/javascript',
      'Content-Type': 'text/javascript',
    }
  }).then(response = >response.json()).then(responseJson = >{
    this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
      return {
        questions: responseJson,
        loading: false
      }
    })
  })
}
```

And when this get request puts responseJson in state I want to call my function that will do something with that array.

If you need any more info please comment.

Comment: What do you mean, wait for it to finish so you can do something with the array? That's exactly what your code already does.

Comment: Yes, I put responseJson in questions in state, but in componentWillMount I need to do something with questions as well. If you understand

Comment: No, I don't understand.

Comment: Oh, never mind man, this is simple, my focus lately is trash, sorry

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just Define the function inside the class and call the function using this.{function_name} as below.

```
myFunction(responseJson) {
  // ... Your code ...
}
componentWillMount() {
  console.log("will mount");
  fetch(baseUrl + 'api/Customer/GetCustomerAccount/' + value, {
    method: 'GET',
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.myFunction(responseJson);
  })
}
```

Comment: But what if I use redux and make a request to the server through action creators. The request to the server does not occur in the component, where it will be most correct to check if the data has loaded if I need to do something with them? For example, apply some kind of filter. Use componentDidUpate() for that?

Comment: Make an async request and return promise from the action either resolve or reject and catch the response or error whatever in the calling function inside the component. So you get the correct way to bind the request with the component

Answer (score 0):

Put an if statement in your render function:

```
 render(){

    if(this.state.loading){
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                // Your code if fetch() still fetching
            </View>
        )
     }

    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
            // Your code if fetch() has ended
            // the complete fetched data is this.state.questions
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added another .then at the end and put the function inside it. In my case, I wanted to log the data received by fetch:

```
fetch(url).then(some function).then(function(){
    console.log(fetchResultData)
})
```

Comment: A good idea would also to that catch so that you can account for any errors that could effect the request output
```fetch(url).then(some function).then(function(){
    console.log(fetchResultData)
}).catch(function(err) { console.log(err) })```